# Modifying duplicate subindex in MultiIndex dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, removing-whitespace

Hi I have a dataframe slice as below:

```
|            |          | Lemon | Orange |
|------------|----------|-------|--------|
| Date       | Location |       |        |
| 01/01/2016 | Park     | 10    | 20     |
| 01/01/2016 | Beach    | 5     | 15     |
| 01/01/2016 | Park     | 2     | 4      |
| 02/01/2016 | Park     | 8     | 3      |
```

As you can see there is a duplicate for `(01/01/2016, Park)` and the reason is because the 3rd entry has a white space after k in Park. I am having a difficulty with my limited index selection skill to do a `rstrip(" ")` on the entire Location column to avoid the whitespace error.

Ultimately, I am hoping to do a `groupby` function to visualise the data between `Park` and other locations. At the moment, `"Park"` and `"Park "` are 2 different locations.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indices are immutable, so if you want to change `index` labels you need to set a new `index` (thanks [IanS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123606/modifying-duplicate-subindex-in-multiindex-dataframe-in-pandas#comment65593081_39123794)).

You can use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) in second level selecting by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
new_index = list(zip(df.index.get_level_values('Date'),
                     df.index.get_level_values('Location').str.strip()))

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index, names = df.index.names)

print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[2016-01-01 00:00:00, 2016-02-01 00:00:00], ['Beach', 'Park']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1]],
           names=['Date', 'Location'])
```

If you want use [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html), replace  `str.strip` to `str.rstrip`.

Comment: Note that indices are immutable, so if you want to change index labels you need to set a new index.

Comment: Exactly, i add it to answer. Thank you IanS.